# C++ Advanced Puzzle

Tags: c++

I've faced with the following question and I do not have a good idea.
Maybe someone can help me?

```
class Foo 
{
    // [Your code goes here] 
    // Rec1: Don’t write function call operator()
    // Rec2: Don’t use macros.
}; 
int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    foo();          // This line prints “Hello World!” 
}
```

Comment: If you have a suggestion please share.  Because it seems difficult without using operators () or macros.

Comment: I don't understand the many downvotes or closing requests. What is unclear? What is missing?

Comment: Do we know whether there is a solution? It seems that `foo()` requires a function call operator (this cannot be avoided by the existence of a function `foo()`), when it would have no solution.

Comment: Walter, I also think that there is no solution, but I'm not sure. Maybe there's a trick.

Comment: @Walter: "I do not have a good idea. Maybe someone can help me?" does not fall into our definition of an acceptable problem statement with clear evidence of research effort. It also has a poor and ambiguous title that doesn't describe the problem in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
class Foo
{
public:
    using fncPntr = void(*)(void);
    //Implicit conversion to a function pointer
    operator fncPntr()
    {
        return &Print;
    }
    void static Print()
    {
        std::cout << "Hello World!";
    }
};
int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    foo();
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
class Foo{
// [Your code goes here] 
};
void foo()
{
    std::cout << "hello";
}
class Bar{
// Rec1: Don’t write function call operator()
// Rec2: Don’t use macros.
};
```

Comment: Sorry, but this won't work: `error: type 'Foo' does not provide a call operator`

Comment: It is assumed that in the body of the class instead of the comment // [Your code goes here] there must be some code and after the run of "Hello world" should be printed.

Comment: Inside `main`, `foo` means the variable of type `Foo`, not a global function of the same name. You'd have to write `::foo` to get that.